# Measure Tool Data from Python

Tags: python, measurement

How can I access the measurements displayed with the Measure Tool in Blender 2.80 from Python?  I'm not seeing it anywhere in the documentation, hoping I'm just blind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credit for this answer goes to the discussion [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/helping-neuroscience-with-the-measure-tool/1186087/13).

The data is stored in the grease pencil annotations:

```
bpy.data.grease_pencils["Annotations"].layers['RulerData3D']
```

Specifically, to get a list of all length measurements currently in the scene:

```
lengths = list((s.points[0].co - s.points[-1].co).length for s in bpy.data.grease_pencils["Annotations"].layers['RulerData3D'].frames[0].strokes)
```